# Google spreadsheet query language, match using regex?

Tags: google-sheets, regex

I have a `query` formula that looks into a table and pulls names for example:

```
   A                   B
1  john, andrew     blah
2  drew, mike       blah
```

I want it to show me all of the rows that involve `drew`, the query formula is `select where A contains 'drew'`. Both rows would show up, because `andrew` contains `drew`, but if I use the formula `select where A = 'drew'`, nothing would show up because it is looking for an exact match. What do I do here? I was thinking maybe regular expression would help, but how would I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To handle word boundaries, you need [`where A matches`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Where) instead of `where A contains`. It allows the use of regular expressions such as `.*\bdrew\b.*`, meaning

- containing the string "drew"
- with word boundaries `\b` left and right of the string (i.e., the characters adjacent to it cannot be word characters)
- with any other characters elsewhere in the string: `.*`

The last bullet item is needed because the logic of `matches` requires the entire content of A to match the given expression (unlike `regexmatch` function, which will attempt to match substrings).

So, in your case it would be

```
=query(A:B, "select * where A matches '.*\bdrew\b.*'")
```

or, if you want to also match "Drew" (case insensitive), then

```
=query(A:B, "select * where lower(A) matches '.*\bdrew\b.*'")
```

Comment: is there a way to use regex in `countifs`? how would the formula change if i use `countifs`. I've tried `countifs(Out!$E$3:$E,".*\b"&B65&"\b.*")`

Comment: Not really. `countif` and `countifs` support only the basic wildcards ? and *, which is not enough to handle word boundaries.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are changing the question from "show me the rows" to "count the rows". Counting can be done with `select count(A)` or with `counta(filter(...))`, but this should be a separate question.